# get field values based on TIMESTAMP

Tags: visualforce

I am having a field where i need to get timestamp in format "createddate+noofrecords".

If i created a record on this day  "1504201401".
01=no of records created on this day. 
How can i achieve the functionality ? pls some one help me out

Comment: Is this something you need in your datamodel (custom field) or is this something you want to display on a custom page (visualforce) ?  By adding more details and context to your question (and using appropriate tags) you will increase the quality of the answers that you receive.

Comment: I want to display feild in vf page. Can u please guide me how we can achieve the functionality.